# Can I buy a game on steam and install it later on a different laptop?

Tags: steam

Long story short I have ordered a new gaming laptop. I want to buy a game in the upcoming steam sales but not install it until I get my new laptop. Maybe 3-4 weeks from now. Will I be able to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, if you buy a game on your Steam account, that game is licensed on your Steam account for your use. You can then just log into your Steam account on any computer and install and play the game as required.

You do not need the Steam client installed to purchase a game [but you do need a Steam account](https://store.steampowered.com/join/), then you can either purchase the game via the Steam website or download the client. You will need the Steam client to install and play the game, though.

Comment: will I need to install the steam client just to buy the game? (noob!)

Comment: There are exceptions to this: games that are on Steam, but also include other DRM, like [Anno 2070](http://store.steampowered.com/app/48240/) (note that the page mentions "3 machine activation limit").

Comment: Some games support cloud saving, so your save games follow you wherever you install the game

Comment: In case of Anno 2070 you get 1 activations per month or some unspecified period. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2677124

Answer (score -2):

I play Dota 2 on steam. You just need one steam account, and you can use your account on any number of machines.

Comment: This question was already answered by @kalina and s/he (not sure really) mentioned same thing.